# Multiple home page for different clients

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

We have different clients asking for home page with different design layout so what is an efficient way to have multiple pages with different styles, layout for the same data coming from the database in a mvc project?

Answer (score 1):

You could have different css and change the design according to the user that has logged in. If the different design includes placement of elements in different places, then you could use a grid system and store in JSON (preferably) the schema of the page. Then, on each login you should load the JSON and place the elements accordingly. Hope that gave you a small hint!

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, it includes placement of elements in different places..please can you post an example of using grid system as JSON. thanks.

Comment: It depends on the libs that you already have on your project.